# I received the following error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Tags: python

I received the following error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

I copied the code exactly as written from the book: "Python Programming: An Introduction to Computer Science", page 44-45. (see below). Where did I go wrong?

```
# investment calculator

def main():
    print ("this program calculates the future value")
    print ("of a 10-year investment.")

    principal = input("Enter the initial principal: ")
    apr = input("Enter the Annual Interest rate: ")

    for i in range (10):
        principal = principal * (1.0 + apr)

    print ("The value in 10 years is: "), principal

main()
```

Comment: Was that book written for python 2? In python 2, `input` calls `eval` on the incoming text, converting it to a python type like `int` or `float`. In python 3, that automatic conversion was removed and all you get is a string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert some of these values into integers, as input is taken as a string. To change this, you can wrap the inputs in the `int()` function like this:

```
principal = int(input("Enter the initial principal: "))
apr = int(input("Enter the Annual Interest rate: "))
```

If this program is being used by other people, you should encase it in a try/except block in case someone gives a value that is not an int. That would look something like this:

```
while True:
    try:
       principal = int(input("Enter the initial principal: "))
       apr = int(input("Enter the Annual Interest rate: "))
       break
    except TypeError:
       print("Value is not an integer")
```

Comment: Thank you but I tried your changes and the program is still not working properly.  I changed the apr line to the following so the user can input decimals (to represent percentages):  apr = int(float(input("Enter the Annual Interest rate: "))) >>> however, the program is not executing properly. I suppose the book I am referencing is outdated